# I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error when I use AJAX on my local

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 error on a WordPress page when I send an AJAX call.

I'm using WP on my local (MAMP). I have a script that sends an ajax call to the WP database. Triggering the call produces the error. I've been troubleshooting this for several hours, but I'm no closer to resolving it.

Here's the pertinent code:

**FUNCTION**
(function.php)

```
function example_ajax_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'example-ajax-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-script.js',
        array('jquery')
    );

    wp_localize_script(
        'example-ajax-script',
        'example_ajax_obj',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_ajax_enqueue' );
```

**JAVASCRIPT**
(custom-script.js)

```
const $ = jQuery;

var themeURL = 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/'; // trying to call the page directly

$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function() {
    search();
});

function search() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: site_url + '/get-list.php', // this file contains all my queries on the WP database
        data: {
            'ajax': '1',
            'item1': GetURLParameter('item1'),
            'item2': GetURLParameter('item2'),
            'limit': GetURLParameter('limit')
        },
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown); // error
        }
    });
}
```

**APACHE (configuration)**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#


#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:\MAMP\htdocs\cbd">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All


    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

#     SetHandler perl-script
#      PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
#      PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
#      Options +ExecCGI
#      Order allow,deny
#      Allow from all 
      
#<IfModule mod_perl.c>
#    # Files directive is only valid in Directory section
#    <Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
#        SetHandler perl-script
#        #PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
#        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
#        allow from all
#
#        PerlSendHeader On
#    </Files>
#  </IfModule>
  
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    
    <IfModule perl_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.pl
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule wsgi_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.wsgi index.py
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "C:/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "C:\MAMP\logs\access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.testauctions.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:\MAMP\cgi-bin"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock C:\MAMP\logs\access.log/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "D:\MAMP\cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
#<Directory "D:\MAMP\cgi-bin">
#    AllowOverride None 
#    Options None
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
#</Directory>


Alias /MAMP "C:/MAMP/bin/MAMP/"

<Directory "C:/MAMP/bin/MAMP/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Alias /phpMyAdmin "C:/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/"

<Directory "C:/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
    
Alias /SQLiteManager "C:/MAMP/bin/SQLiteManager/"

<Directory "C:/MAMP/bin/SQLiteManager/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

Alias /phpLiteAdmin "C:/MAMP/bin/phpLiteAdmin/"

<Directory "C:/MAMP/bin/phpLiteAdmin/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    DirectoryIndex phpliteadmin.php
</Directory>
```

***ERROR**
http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child//get-list.php?ajax=1&_=1599016122801 403 (Forbidden) custom-script.js?ver=5.5.1:72*

I'm unsure if the plugin I'm using, Beaver Builder, is the problem. I tried the BB support forum, but didn't see a solution. I've also tried going directly to the file in my browser, and I'm blocked. I've checked file and directory permissions - I have them. I've permissions in my Apache - it's set to allow for all. I've used a variation of this script before with no issues.

One thing of note, the function and script are in the child theme directory.

I could use some assistance. I'll continue to troubleshoot in the meantime.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your Apache error log say?

Comment: [Tue Sep 01 22:53:06 2020] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/MAMP/htdocs/cbd/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/get-list.php, referer: http://localhost:8888/careers/open-positions-test/?page=3